# Hadoop pig join with time range

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two data sets

```
Master.txt
ID,StartTime
1,2013-04-01 00:01:37
2,2013-04-01 00:01:37

Transaction.txt
ID,SurveyDate,Attr1
1,2013-04-01 00:03:40,Success
2,2013-05-01 00:01:30,Success
```

I want to join those two datasets with `ID` and (`SurveyDate-StartTime` < 24hrs) and add `Attr1` to Master.

I loaded Master and Transaction using Load in pig and I can do join on ID but I'm not able to find the Transactions which are within 24 hours of `Master.StartTime`.

`Master.txt` has significant number of records where Transactions are very few.

here is code

```
master=load 'hdfs://localhost:9000/user/xyz/contact/master' using PigStorage(',') as (ID,StartTime) 

transaction=load 'hdfs://localhost:9000/user/xyz/contact/transaction' using PigStorage(',') as 
(ID,SurveyDate,Attr1)

combine=join master by ID left outer, transaction ID
```

This is so far I have, as i understand from documentation conditions are not allowed when joining datasets. So not sure how would i add something like Master.StartTime-Transaction.SurveyDate <=24hrs

Comment: Please show your current effort in code.

Comment: Edit your post instead of posting in comments

Comment: I have edited post as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to add a filter stage after the join:

```
combine = join master by ID left outer, transaction ID
combine = FILTER combine BY ((StartTime - SurveyDate) < (24*60*60*1000));
```

(assuming your start time and survey times are long representing the ms since the epoch)

Comment: Chris, I also wanted to keep all records from master and add attributes from transaction to master.ID where ((StartTime - SurveyDate) < (24*60*60*1000))

Comment: the attributes should come as part of the join - but if you have multiple attributes (multiple records with the same (ID,SurveyDate) key), then you'll need to check whether you get a cartesian product and then perform a group by the ID / dates to produce a bag of attributes